# Parsing a YouTube request

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing

i have a problem while parsing youtube request.
I want to extract the  nodes from the response but my code returns always zero.
this is the code snippet:

```
        public void parser(string id)
    {
        WebClient wc = new WebClient();
        string urlContents = wc.DownloadString("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/"+id);
        XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
        xml.LoadXml(urlContents);
        var nsm = new XmlNamespaceManager(xml.NameTable);
        nsm.AddNamespace("t1", "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom");
        nsm.AddNamespace("t2", "http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/");
        var title = xml.SelectNodes("/t1:entry/t2:thumbnail", nsm);
        Console.WriteLine(title.Count);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

This is the xml file

```
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<entry xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom' xmlns:media='http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/' xmlns:gd='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005' xmlns:yt='http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007'>
<id>http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/t5QAfTGVxuo</id>
<published>2010-07-08T03:08:21.000Z</published>
<updated>2014-03-03T02:47:19.000Z</updated>
<category scheme='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind' term='http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007#video'/><category scheme='http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007/categories.cat' term='Entertainment' label='Divertissement'/>
<title type='text'>Pharrell | Chelsea Lately</title>
</content>
<link rel='alternate' type='text/html' href='http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t5QAfTGVxuo&amp;feature=youtube_gdata'/>
<link rel='http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007#video.related' type='application/atom+xml' href='http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/t5QAfTGVxuo/related'/>
<link rel='http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007#mobile' type='text/html' href='http://m.youtube.com/details?v=t5QAfTGVxuo'/><link rel='self' type='application/atom+xml' href='http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/t5QAfTGVxuo'/>
<author>
<name>ChelseaLately</name>
<uri>http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/ChelseaLately</uri>
</author>
<gd:comments>
<gd:feedLink rel='http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007#comments' href='http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/t5QAfTGVxuo/comments' countHint='1892'/>
</gd:comments><media:group><media:category label='Divertissement' scheme='http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007/categories.cat'>Entertainment</media:category>
<media:content url='http://www.youtube.com/v/t5QAfTGVxuo?version=3&amp;f=videos&amp;app=youtube_gdata' type='application/x-shockwave-flash' medium='video' isDefault='true' expression='full' duration='375' yt:format='5'/>
<media:content url='rtsp://r8---sn-4g57kuez.c.youtube.com/CiILENy73wIaGQnqxpUxfQCUtxMYDSANFEgGUgZ2aWRlb3MM/0/0/0/video.3gp' type='video/3gpp' medium='video' expression='full' duration='375' yt:format='1'/>
<media:content url='rtsp://r8---sn-4g57kuez.c.youtube.com/CiILENy73wIaGQnqxpUxfQCUtxMYESARFEgGUgZ2aWRlb3MM/0/0/0/video.3gp' type='video/3gpp' medium='video' expression='full' duration='375' yt:format='6'/>
<media:description type='plain'>Pharrell chats about his latest animated film "Despicable Me.
</media:description>
<media:keywords/>
<media:player url='http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t5QAfTGVxuo&amp;feature=youtube_gdata_player'/>
<media:thumbnail url='http://i1.ytimg.com/vi/t5QAfTGVxuo/0.jpg' height='360' width='480' time='00:03:07.500'/>
<media:thumbnail url='http://i1.ytimg.com/vi/t5QAfTGVxuo/1.jpg' height='90' width='120' time='00:01:33.750'/>
<media:thumbnail url='http://i1.ytimg.com/vi/t5QAfTGVxuo/2.jpg' height='90' width='120' time='00:03:07.500'/>
<media:thumbnail url='http://i1.ytimg.com/vi/t5QAfTGVxuo/3.jpg' height='90' width='120' time='00:04:41.250'/>
<media:title type='plain'>Pharrell | Chelsea Lately</media:title><yt:duration seconds='375'/></media:group>
<gd:rating average='4.8432107' max='5' min='1' numRaters='5332' rel='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#overall'/>
<yt:statistics favoriteCount='0' viewCount='2085078'/>
</entry>
```

i hope that my question is clear so that you could help me

Comment: Any reason you're not using LINQ to XML? It's generally much simpler to use, particularly with namespaces.

Comment: And the XML you've provided is invalid to start with - you've got a `</content>` closing tag but no `<content>` opening tag...

Comment: there is no reason but i just found this example and it looks easy to understand

Comment: yes there is an openeing <content> node but it looks like i removed it because the text is too long ... sorry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The immediate problem is that you've ignored the intervening `media:group` element which contains the `media:thumbnail` elements. So you can change your XPath to:

```
var title = xml.SelectNodes("/t1:entry/t2:group/t2:thumbnail", nsm);
```

It's *much* easier to see this if you format your XML when you're diagnosing issues:

```
<entry>
  ...
  <media:group>
    ...
    <media:thumbnail ... />
    <media:thumbnail ... />
    ...
  </media:group>
</entry>
```

Personally I'd use LINQ to XML though:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/"+id);
XNamespace media = "http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/";
var thumbnails = doc.Root
                    .Elements(media + "group")
                    .Elements(media + "thumbnail");
```

Comment: it always return zero

Comment: @RamiRaddaoui: Then the XML you've provided must be inaccurate. I took the *exact* XML you provided, removed the `</content>` line, and both of the above queries returned 4 elements.

Comment: the problem persists until now.i changed th id of the video but nothing changed

Comment: Well as I say, the code I've given works with the XML you've given. So either you haven't taken my code correctly, or the XML you've given in the question isn't representative. Either way, you should be able to use the suggestions in this answer to help you diagnose it further. In particular, format the XML locally so you can see the structure.

Comment: Thank you @Jon Skeet.u are right.i used wml to linq and it works fine